# Why can I be logged in to the same domain on Internet Explorer and Chrome but not with FireFox and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, logging

I did not test all the scenarios, but it seems like there is some log in issues if you log in on the same domain on FF and Chrome, however you can perfectly do it with IE and Chrome/FF (referring to being able to log in simultaneously with two different users on the same domain on the same machine) .

My questions is: is there a general reason why is this the case? If not, what specifics does this relate to?

Addendum: I don't know "any more information" - this is just the surface behavior I observed and asking if anyone can explain why is this happening. Maybe it isn't supposed to be happening at all?

Thanks, 
M.B.

Comment: Huh? Please provide much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce it. Seems like I was mistaken in my perceptions